# Custom block template doesn't print content

Tags: nodes

I have custom block template built based on Drupal 7 examples, but it always returns empty content for me:

```
<div class="caption-text clearfix">
<?= $block->title; ?>
</div>
<div class="regular-text clearfix">
<?= $block->content; ?>
</div>
```

Though when I call it from my page.tpl.php it works well:

```
$block = block_load('block', '1');
    $output =     drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block))));
    print $output;
```

I just need to control where I output the title and content, having my own HTML layout for them.

Please assist.

THanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Avoid short tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/200666/967168) as not all servers support them.

Use:

```
<?php print $block->content; ?>
```

Instead of:

```
<?= $block->content; ?>
```

Also in [block.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.tpl.php/7) I would expect to see `<?php print $content; ?>` instead of `$block->content`.

Comment: Thanks but that's not an answer. That's my server and I definitely enabled support for short tags, besides, I tried with <?php print, as well <?= $block->title; ?> works, but not content.

Comment: Comment to your edit: Fun, https://drupal.org/node/11813 this says something else :/ And.... $content worked. Thanks

Comment: [Drupal coding standards](https://drupal.org/coding-standards#phptags) say to always use <?php ?>. Also use $content, not $block->content.

Comment: @Fratyr This _is_ an answer - it might not apply to your server setup, but since you haven't declared that, how could we know?